# $A.getCallback() throwing uncaught error: [key.indexOf is not a function]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to create a simple component that will query Contacts whose Ice_Cream_Preference__c field is equal to the current Account's Ice_Cream_Specialty__c field and display those names in an iteration. On click of the lightning:button I'm getting the following error : "$A.getCallback() throwing uncaught error: [key.indexOf is not a function]". I don't know where key.indexOf is coming from. Can anybody point out the error in my code? Much appreciated.

getInterestedContacts.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId"
            controller="findIceCreamContact">
<aura:attribute name="Contacts" type="Contact[]"
                default="{'sobjectType':'Contact',
                        'Name':'Rodrigo Duterte'}"/>
<lightning:button label="Find Matches" onclick="{!c.myAction}"/>
<h3>Contact Matches</h3>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.Contacts}" var="con">
    {!con.Name}, {!con.Ice_Cream_Preference__c}
    <br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

getInterestedContactsController.js

```
({
myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var matchConts = component.get("c.getContacts");

    var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
    if(recordId==null) return;

    matchConts.setParams({
    "accountId":recordId
    });

    matchConts.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS"){
          component.set('v.Contacts', response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else{
            console.log("failed with state: "+ state);
        }
    }); 
    $A.enqueueAction(matchConts);
}
})
```

findIceCreamContact.apxc

```
public with sharing class findIceCreamContact {

@AuraEnabled
public static Contact[] getContacts(ID accountId){
    List<Account> foundAcct = [SELECT Ice_Cream_Specialty__c, Id
                               FROM Account 
                               WHERE ID=:accountId];

    return [SELECT Id, Ice_Cream_Preference__c 
            FROM Contact
            WHERE Ice_Cream_Preference__c =:foundAcct[0].Ice_Cream_Specialty__c];      
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `Name` field from your Contact Query. You are referencing it in your iteration.